# How to set ViewPort Size in Python Selenium PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, viewport

Trying to figure out how I can set the viewport size (initial window size). I already know that I can use `driver.set_window_size(1920,1080)` but that only sets the window size for 1 tab, if there is more than 1 tab open, the other tabs are not that size. Plus I think it only sets the window size after the page is rendered, I want the window size already set before the page is rendered. Below is what I have tried so far. If anyone knows how to set the viewport size, it would be much appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)

dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
    "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36"
)

dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.viewportSize"] = (
    "width: 1920, "
    "height: 1080"
)

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)

driver.get('https://www.test.com')
```

Comment: Set the window size before you navigate to the desired page. You can also loop through all open windows and set the window size.

Comment: Does not work because that second window will not be that window size. And looping through all the windows and setting the size does not work either because it is setting the size after the page is rendered. I need to set the window size before the page is rendered. If you look here http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html it can be done but I do not know how to do it in Python/Selenium.

Comment: any solution to this?, its a infuriating problem for me :(